# Chart.js - Why the chart cannot rendered in a child component but in the father component can?

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

i tried to do a chart in a father component with a children component but i can't, this is my code.

Father component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tickets',
  template: '<canvas id="newChart"></canvas>'
})
export class TicketsComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {

    var chart = new Chart('newChart', {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
          datasets: 
          [
            {
              label: 'Total De Cada Mes',
              data: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(0, 123, 155, 1)',
              borderWidth: 2
            },
            {
              label: 'Total de domicilios',
              data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(12, 092, 323, 0.5)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(12, 092, 323, 1)',
              borderWidth: 2,
              hidden: true
            }
          ]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This look like this:
[image]

But if i tried to do the same thing in a child component, this happens.

Father component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tickets',
  template: '<app-tickets-chart id="newChart"></app-tickets-chart>'
})
export class TicketsComponent {
}
```

Children Component (With the same chart):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tickets-chart',
  template: "<canvas [id]='chartId'></canvas>"
})
export class TicketsChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input()
  public chartId: string;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     if(this.chartId === '') {
      throw new Error("Attribute 'chartId' is required.");
    }

    var chart = new Chart(this.chartId, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
          datasets: 
          [
            {
              label: 'Total De Cada Mes',
              data: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(0, 123, 155, 1)',
              borderWidth: 2
            },
            {
              label: 'Total de domicilios',
              data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(12, 092, 323, 0.5)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(12, 092, 323, 1)',
              borderWidth: 2,
              hidden: true
            }
          ]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And this look like this:

[image]

What i have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add this styles in child component and i resolved my problem.

```
:host {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

That's all.